# Do not restart IIS when map files changes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, iis, gulp, map-files

I debug a site on the local IIS (localhost).

I use a tool (*Gulp*) to generate minified JS files directly from "dev" to the "dist" folder that is used by the server.

*Gulp* watches the `dev/my.js` file and once modified genetates the

```
dist/my.min.js
dist/maps/my.min.js.map
```

This *should permit* to see directly the modifications on the server, without rebuilding/redeploying the entire site, there is need just to refresh the page...

The problem is the generated `map` file.. The local IIS thinks that this is a binary file change, and restarts/recycle the server once binary files are changed...

So in order to see my change is JavaScript I need to wait until the local server is refreshed (so it removes any advantage of generating files with GULP)...

Is there a way to say to IIS do NOT recycle itself when `.map` files are changed?

Hopefully for the `.css` files the trik works, because there is no map files associated with the `.min.css` files

Comment: Do you mean .min or .map? You seem to change. The extension of the file is .map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to disable the IIS refresh only for `.map` files only (this seems to be an all or nothing proposition), but in your site's web.config, go the `httpRuntime` element and add fcnMode="Disabled". So, you'd end up with a line looking like this:

```
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" />
```

What that does is tell IIS to stop looking for file changes in the site directory, which means that **changes to no code and the web.config will be ignored until the site unloads**. (Either via you manually starting/restarting or IIS shutting it down after a period of inactivity.)